# Manually configure a Hibernate SessionFactory in OSGi

Tags: java, hibernate, osgi, sessionfactory

a while ago I finally managed to get an OSGi Service that uses Hibernate to work.
My current task is changing this Service into a Managed Service. Basicly I'm supposed to change my Configuration at runtime to decide between 2 databases, but that I'm not really sure how. I get my SessionFactory like this:

```
ServiceReference<?> ref = context.getServiceReference(SessionFactory.class.getName());
            SessionFactory factory = (SessionFactory) context.getService(ref);
```

To my knowlegde, that's the only viable way to get a SessionFactory in OSGi, but the entire Configuration is done in the `org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiSessionFactoryService`.

My question is, is there any way to configure my SessionFactory manually, like changing the used hibernate.cfg.xml or using `.setProperty("connection.url", "...")` ?

The only solution I can imagine is to use a heavily modified `OsgiSessionFactoryService`, but that seems slightly overkill...

Does anyone have a more elegant approach to this problem?